# Umbraco MVC Error loading Partial View script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, umbraco

I have been stuck at this point for a while. The form comes up well, but does not validate. Also when I hit submit I get the error:
 "Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/ApplicationFormStub.cshtml)"

I am no quite sure where I went wrong and would greatly appreciate your advice on the correct direction for getting the form to validate and atleast go through.

Here is my model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ApplicationMetaData))]
public partial class Application { }
public class ApplicationMetaData
{
    [DisplayName("Employer Name")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Employer's Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Supervisor Name")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Supervisor's Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public string SupervisorName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Supervisor Title")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Supervisor's Title")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public string SupervisorTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employer Address")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Employer's Address")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public string EmployerAddress { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employer City")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Employer's City")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public string EmployerCity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employer State")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Employer's State")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public object EmployerState { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employer Zip")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Employer's Zip")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Only 50 Characters allowed")]
    public string EmployerZip { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employer Phone")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Only 10 Characters allowed")]
    public string EmployerPhone { get; set; }
 }
```

Macro Partials file:

```
@Html.Action("ShowApplication", "ServicesSurface")
```

Surface Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ShowApplication")]
    public ActionResult ShowApplication()
    {           
        return PartialView("ServicesApplicationForm", new ApplicationMetaData());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ActionName("ShowApplication")]
    public ActionResult ShowApplication(ApplicationMetaData Model)
        {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }

         try
             {
              //Linq Data Entry
             }
         catch (Exception oe)
             {
             Response.Write(oe.Message);
             Response.End();
             }
         //Send Email 
         return RedirectToAction(RedirectUrl);
        }
```

View:

```
@using Umbraco.Web
@using UmbracoProd.code
@model Umbraco.Services.ApplicationMetaData

<script src="@Url.Content("/../../scripts/libs/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/../../scripts/libs/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("/../../css/Services/form.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("ShowApplication", "ServicesSurface"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="FormArea">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Section One</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployerName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployerName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployerName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SupervisorName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SupervisorName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SupervisorName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SupervisorTitle)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SupervisorTitle)
            </li>
             <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SupervisorTitle)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployerAddress)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployerAddress)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployerAddress)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployerCity)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployerCity)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployerCity)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployerState)                    
                @Html.StateDropDownList("EmployerState", "IN")
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployerState)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployerZip)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployerZip)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployerZip)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployerPhone)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployerPhone)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployerPhone)
            </li>                              
        </ul>
    </fieldset>        
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
  </div> 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error saying that the ApplicationMetaData has no definition for @Html.StateDropDownList().

When I commented that bit out of the form I got another error after going into the controller and failing to validate which said "Can only use UmbracoPageResult in the context of an Http POST when using" etc..

I found the answer I think from [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/41357-return-CurrentUmbracoPage%28%29-results-in-Error-loading-Partial-View-script?p=0#comment151299) basically:

> After the post when the Reset action is run the second time, since the
>   modelstate is maintained, by passing a newly instantiated model, this
>   model will inherit the model state of the model processed in the POST
>   action (PostReset).
>
> During the second time the Reset action was called, since the token
>   data has been corrupted along the lines somewhere the token validation
>   fails and it never gets to the point where it returns the partial
>   view.

i.e. don't create another model send the same one back, I changed the failed validation code in the ShowApplication POST to

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("ServicesApplicationForm", Model);
    }
```

and at least I got back to the validated form, with it validating, it's not in the page anymore for me but I'll leave the fun bit to you.

Comment: The validation is atleast  covered for now on a positive note but I still get that error nagging

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but I had a similar error message that was due to database permissions.

I had SQL server authentication enabled and the user I had created didn't have execute permissions on the database, I granted the permission and the errror disappeared.

Maybe this will help someone.